# Objetivo inalcanzable, 'rol' devolvió nulo type Informe de Excepción JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jpa

Espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy intentando registrar un empleado. Estoy trabajando con JSF, Primefaces y JPA. Adjunto mi código:

Clase Empleado (JPA)

```
package com.cibertec.edu.gestion.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the empleado database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="empleado")
public class Empleado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String idempleado;

    private String apellido;

    private String clave;

    private String dni;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaRegistro;

    @Lob
    private byte[] foto;

    private String nombre;

    private String sexo;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Rol
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idrol")
    private Rol rol;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Socio
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="empleado")
    private List<Socio> socios;

    public Empleado() {
    }

    public String getIdempleado() {
        return this.idempleado;
    }

    public void setIdempleado(String idempleado) {
        this.idempleado = idempleado;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return this.apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return this.clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return this.dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return this.fechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }

    public byte[] getFoto() {
        return this.foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(byte[] foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return this.sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Rol getRol() {
        return this.rol;
    }

    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    public List<Socio> getSocios() {
        return this.socios;
    }

    public void setSocios(List<Socio> socios) {
        this.socios = socios;
    }

    public Socio addSocio(Socio socio) {
        getSocios().add(socio);
        socio.setEmpleado(this);

        return socio;
    }

    public Socio removeSocio(Socio socio) {
        getSocios().remove(socio);
        socio.setEmpleado(null);

        return socio;
    }
```

}

Clase Rol(JPA)

```
package com.cibertec.edu.gestion.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the rol database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="rol")
public class Rol implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idrol;

    private String descripcion;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Empleado
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rol")
    private List<Empleado> empleados;

    public Rol() {
    }

    public int getIdrol() {
        return this.idrol;
    }

    public void setIdrol(int idrol) {
        this.idrol = idrol;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public List<Empleado> getEmpleados() {
        return this.empleados;
    }

    public void setEmpleados(List<Empleado> empleados) {
        this.empleados = empleados;
    }

    public Empleado addEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        getEmpleados().add(empleado);
        empleado.setRol(this);

        return empleado;
    }

    public Empleado removeEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        getEmpleados().remove(empleado);
        empleado.setRol(null);

        return empleado;
    }

}
```

Clase EmpleadoManaged

```
@ManagedBean(empleadomanaged)
public class EmpleadoManaged implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
private EmpleadoService service;
private List<Empleado> listaEmpleado;
private StreamedContent imagen;
private String codigo;

public EmpleadoManaged() {

    service = new EmpleadoServiceImpl();
}
///............................
//get and sert , del objeto empleado//
```

Mi problema surge aqui en este trozo de codigo de .xhtml cuando ingreso a mi pagina empleado.xhtml me bota el siguiente error Objetivo inalcanzable, 'rol' devolvió nulo type Informe de Excepción.Por favor necesito ayuda.

```
 <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{empleadomanaged.empleado.rol.idrol}">
      <f:selectItem 
      itemLabel="--Seleccione--"
      itemValue="0"/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{rolmanaged.roles}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.descripcion}" itemValue="#{c.idrol}"/>

 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la linea siguiente se ve que instancias un objeto de Empleado:

```
private Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
```

Pero no le agregas dentro un objeto Rol al que pueda referenciar JSF. Por lo que debería ser:

```
private Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
empleado.setRol(new Rol());
```

También esto no lo debes hacer en zona de declaración de variables sino luego de que se instancie el ManagedBean por lo que lo ideal es que se cree un método con la etiqueta `@PostConstruct` dentro de la clase `ManagedBean` siendo finalmente:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    empleado = new Empleado();
    empleado.setRol(new Rol());
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo , te lo agradezco bastante ,hace dos semanas busque información pero no encontraba nada , pero gracias a tu comentario lo logre ahora si por fin puedo seguir avanzando mi proyecto.

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudar :)

Answer (score 0):

fue de mucha ayuda.

```
empleado.setRol(new Rol())
```

, el error se generaba porque no se crea el Objeto Rol

Comment: Hola llopezg esta área es para respuestas sobre la pregunta revisa [answer], si tienes un comentario puedes obtener reputación, no olvides realiza el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento, saludos.